# What is the point of not allowing extended discussions in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

I don't understand why extended discussions in comments usually get moved to chat. Long threads are collapsed be default, so they don't require significantly more scrolling to get to other content. The comment UI is much more visible, and *far* more user-friendly, especially on mobile devices. If a conversation gets moved to chat, I basically can't participate anymore, because I use SE from my phone much more than from a laptop or desktop, and chat is basically unusable on the phone.

Comment: [This Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362219/) does a good job laying out the reasoning. Hopefully it will soon be included in the message that is left behind when the comments are deleted.

Comment: They are not allowed because we are a Q&A site, not a Q, A & endless comment threads with multiple participants that refuse to reach consensus so the Q or A can be improved site.

Comment: Do you use mobile chat? Because I use chat on my phone all the time and I don't have any issues. :/

Comment: @Catija I think so. When I tap the text box at the bottom to type, it does select it and I can type, but the box isn't visible, so I can't see what I'm typing.

Comment: It sometimes works, but the issue happens often enough that I just give up on conversations that get moved.

Comment: @Catija sadly I agree with OP about chat being unusable on mobile. The mobile chat theme looks better, but is incomplete and buggy.

Comment: Chat works well on a phone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP9KT.png

Comment: @Rob no. It's impossible to show the bad user experience with screenshots, it's just a fact and kind of personal experience being bad. It's *technically possible* to use the chat, but it's really tough and terrible experience. It needs a massive overhaul.

Comment: See: ["How has "move comments to chat" affected users' behavior?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261085/282094), ["What is the desired practice for comment discussions?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266189/282094), and ["Why isn't "Comments are not for extended discussion" the case on Meta?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/305890/282094).

Comment: @Sha, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384254/what-is-the-point-of-not-allowing-extended-discussions-in-comments?noredirect=1#comment1281602_384254

Comment: @Rob so those are 2 vs. 2, we're even.

Comment: @Sha, not even. Ping her, and question her opinion; as you did to me.

Answer (score 6):

Stack Exchange is a collection of Q&A sites, meaning Questions and Answers.

Therefore, the main focus, actually the *only* focus, is the questions and the answers, and that's it.

Anything else exists only to support better quality of the questions and answers, and should be used only for that purpose.

This also includes comments: as the comment textbox placeholder says:

> Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid answering questions in comments.

While it does not explicitly says "no discussions", it's pretty much implied. Discussions in comments do not do anything towards "ask for clarification or add more information" which is the goal of comments.

Let's take some imaginary example. Suppose there is a question:

> I have a code `function doThis(arg1, arg2)` however when calling it I get error *null pointer exception*, how to fix it?

Now, some valid comments can be:

- How exactly are you calling the function?
- What is the code inside the function?

etc. After OP edits with the requested details, such comments become obsolete and can be deleted. That's how comments should be used.

However, suppose someone posting such comment:

> I noticed you are from Australia in your profile, I heard life there are good.

Then the OP replies and there's a discussion about the life in Australia. That adds nothing to the question, or to others who are not interested in those things. That's exactly what chat exists for.